# How to add php plugin in Netbeans 8.1 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, php, netbeans

I have installed **Netbeans 8.1** in **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** from Ubuntu Software. I want to add **php** plugin in Netbeans but php plugin is not available in Netbeans' plugin section.

How do I add php plugin in Netbeans 8.1?

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Tools -> Plugins`. In the `Settings` tab, ensure that the *Update Center* is active.

Then in the `Available Plugins` tab, click on `Reload Catalog`. Hopefully, you will see `PHP` in the `Available Plugins` tab.
Just install it!

**Helpful Links and References**

1. [Configuring the PHP Development Environment in Linux Ubuntu](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html#separate-packages)
2. [How to enable PHP support in Netbeans in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473109/how-to-enable-php-support-in-netbeans)

Comment: I have already try this but in plugin section PHP not found.

Comment: Then I recommend you to download whole Netbeans bundle from their website and install it instead of installing it from Ubuntu Software.